# Expression of graph of a vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am wondering if there is any algebraic definition for the graph of a vector field.

I know that for functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the graph of $f$ is given by $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid z=f(x,y)\}$. So, for example, the graph of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is given by $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid z=x^2+y^2\}$.

My question is how to describe the graph of a vector field. Say we have the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x,y)=(x^2+x-2y^2+1,-x^2+y^2+3y-2)$. I believe the graph of this function should sit inside $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$, however, I am confused how to express this similarly to the example given above. I am ultimately trying to find the intersection of the graph of this function with the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $\{(x,y,x,y)\}$. Is there a way to do this just with the expression given above?

Comment: How about $\{(x, y, z, w) \in \mathbb{R}^{4} \mid z = x^{2} + x - 2y^{2} + 1, w = -x^{2} + y^{2} + 3y - 2\}$?

Comment: From this, how can I get the intersection with the set of points listed above? Is that by simply plugging in $x$ and $y$ for $z$ and $w$, respectively?

Comment: There is no need to intersect this with the set of points above, as this _is_ the set of point that are the graph of the function. I am unsure as to why you want a set of points of the form $(x, y, x, y)$.

Comment: I want to ultimately decide whether the graph of f is transversal to the set of points listed, the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$. To do so I need to determine whether the sum of their respective tangent spaces at every point in their intersection equals all of $\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Here you  can see some method used by Wolfram: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PlotAVectorField.html

Comment: @ponchan Yes, you are correct --- see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, the graph of $f$ is given by $\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid z=f(x,y)\}$. This is because we identify the image of $f$ with a third variable, namely $z$, sitting in another copy of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x,y)=(x^2+x-2y^2+1,-x^2+y^2+3y-2)$, as in your question. This has two values in its image, so you are correct that the graph sits in $\mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2} = \mathbb{R}^{4}$. If we write $f(x, y) = (z, w) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then the graph of $f$ is the set
$$
\{(x, y, z, w) \in \mathbb{R}^{4} \mid z = x^2+x-2y^2+1, w = -x^2+y^2+3y-2\}.
$$
If you want to intersect this with all points $(x, y, x, y)$, then you want $(x, y, z, w) = (x, y, x, y)$ so you are solving $z = x$ and $w = y$. That is, you are solving
$$
x = x^2+x-2y^2+1, \hspace{20pt} y = -x^2+y^2+3y-2.
$$

Comment: Would I even need this representation to determine they are transversal? Or do I simply calculate the jacobian of f?

Comment: I have never come across this transversal property, so I am unsure.

Comment: Well, if I am looking for the tangent space to the graph of $f$, is that just the jacobian of $f$?